# Модификация данных JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit

```
Приведу упрощенный пример:
Иммеется класс:

    LeagueTable{
    @SerializedName("rank")
    @Expose
    int rank;

    @SerializedName("points")
    @Expose
    int points;

    //setters and getters...
    }

JSON respond:

    [{"rank":0, "points":3},
    {"rank":0, "points":1}, 
    {"rank":0, "points":5}, 
    {"rank":0, "points":7}]

з.ы. то есть с сервера данные приходят в недоработанном виде ("rank":0)

Как можно изменить формат JSON (и можно ли вообще) объекта используя GsonConverterFactory.create(), например? Тоесть используя

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("some_link")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

Мне нужно динамически определять rank по points и создавать уже объекты с соответствующим значением rank.

Можно, конечно, получить данные и уже потом через свой метод установить эти значения, но подозреваю, что есть способ лучше, хотя на форумах нашел только простые преобразования форматов, наподобие:

     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();
```

Comment: Пост-обработка выглядит проще всего. Я бы не мудрил.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Думаю, через Rx реализовать функцию в map...

Comment: RX хороший подход. от ретрофита вы получаете уже модельные классы, потом в map/flatMap делаете с ними что хотите и получаете готовые данные. мудрить со своими сериализаторами не стоит

Comment: Понял, сомнения прочь. Просто тема для меня новая, пока плаваю...спасибо